# How to find the floating point precision of a tensorflow model (frozen graph in .pb format),onnx model(.onnx format) like whether it is FP32 or FP16?

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, tensorrt

I am trying to convert a frozen graph of a resnet-50 model to onnx model and then to tensorRT. I want to make sure the floating point precision at each conversion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are passing an image x to the model like model(x) or model.forward(x), then you can check the datatype of x.
You can use dtype property to get the type of a tensorflow variable.

```
> x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 100]))
> x.dtype

<dtype: 'float32_ref'>
```

You can use as_numpy_dtype property of dtype to convert from tf.dtype to numpy dtype.

```
> x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 100]))
> x.dtype.as_numpy_dtype
<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

For Onnx, you can import the onnx/graphsurgeon library to perform various operations. But the easiest way would be to use [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron).

1. pip install netron
2. open https://localhost:8080
3. Click the input node
4. The information panel on the right would give a lot of information including data-type.